# Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter failed in IIS

Tags: tomcat, iis

I am facing a strange issue while configuring Tomcat 9 with IIS 10. This error is what i'm getting.

> Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter
> "C:\Users\Y2K\dev\util\Tomcat Connector\bin\isapi_redirect.dll" failed

I've done everything what apache tomcat say from its docs such as isapi_redirect.dll, sapi_redirect.properties, workers.properties, uriworkermap.properties of course all setting of IIS manager as well filter, virtual directory and so on.

Here is my properties:

```
# Configuration file for the Tomcat ISAPI Redirector

# The path to the ISAPI Redirector Extension, relative to the website
# This must be in a virtual directory with execute privileges
extension_uri=/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll

# Full path to the log file for the ISAPI Redirector
log_file=C:\Users\Y2K\dev\util\Tomcat Connector\log\isapi_redirect.log

# Log level (debug, info, warn, error or trace)
log_level=info

# Full path to the workers.properties file
worker_file=C:\Users\Y2K\dev\util\Tomcat Connector\conf\workers.properties

# Full path to the uriworkermap.properties file
worker_mount_file=C:\Users\Y2K\dev\util\Tomcat Connector\conf\uriworkermap.properties

worker.list=worker1

worker.worker1.type=ajp13

worker.worker1.host=localhost

worker.worker1.port=8009

/*.jsp=worker1
```

According to tomcat docs i should be able to execute jsp files but i'm constantly getting an error i said above.

--edited--

This is the full error page what i'm getting now.
hope it gives you more information.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YfOh.png)

Comment: make sure you enable  Enable 32 Bit Applications of application[image](https://imgur.com/a/ZimYK6K)and check the excutable path of the dll file is correct or not.by opining iis ispi filter feature. could you share detail error message?

Comment: but they said In a 64 Bit environment the used IIS Application Pool should have "Enable 32-bit Applications" set to "False". and my environment is 64 bit so i set that feature to false.